# pageshow event not firing Jquery Mobile and a progress bar is seen but the page is not changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page as shown in the code below that loads properly upon changepage from another .html page. I am aware that changepage in jquery mobile means the new page gets loaded into the current DOM. So I have include the pageshow even handler inside the . But now when I try to change page I see a unending progress indicator and the changepage is not happening.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Demo Mobile AUI</title>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WebSocketConnection.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--MAIN SCREEN-->
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#home').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
                    alert("pageshow");
                });
            </script>
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" align="center">
                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <h1>
                    <a href="login.html" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext">Back</a>
                    <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Menu</a> 
                    <a href="login.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" >Log Out</a>
                    <a href="#settings" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Settings</a>
                </h1>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                <div data-role="collapsible-set">

                  <!-- Transmitter Configuration Collapsible List -->
                  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                    <h3>Transmitter Configuration</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">    
                      <li>Power: <div id="power"></div></li>
                      <li>Set Point:</li>
                      <li>Reflected Power:</li>   
                      <li>Frequency:</li>
                      <li>
                        <label for="preset_list" class="select">Preset:</label>
                        <select name="preset_list" id="select-choice-0" data-inset="false" data-theme="a"></select>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Tool Menu Collapsible List -->
                  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3>Tool Menu</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false"><li>
                    <form action="form.php" method="post">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                      <label for="graph" class="select">Current Graph:</label>
                      <select name="graph" id="select-choice-0" data-inset="false" data-theme="a">
                        <option value="spectrum">Spectrum</option>
                        <option value="EqFreq">EQ Frequency Response</option>
                        <option value="EqImpulse">EQ Impulse Response</option>
                        <option value="EqFilter">EQ Filter Delay</option>
                        <option value="lissajous">Lissajous Plot</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    </li></ul>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Transmitter Log Collapsible List -->
                  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3>Transmitter Log</h3>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Meters Collapsible List -->    
                  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-inset="false">
                    <h3>Meter Readings</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false"><li>
                    <div id="checkBoxList">
                        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-inset="false">
                            <h3>Controller</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-inset="false">
                            <h3>Exciter</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <textarea cols="40" rows="3" name="textarea" id="info_log" height="auto" width="auto"></textarea>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div data-role="footer" align="center">
                    &copy; Copyright  by Nautel Limited
              </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to find a solution to this problem, and even though I have tried many none of them has resolved the problem.

Regards,
Shreyas

Comment: No, I just see a progress indicator but the screen doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` is depreciated. Don't use it going forward. I have noticed that it is working before `jQuery Mobile 1.2.x` but stopped working after `1.3.x`.

Change your code as below.

```
$('#home').on('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    alert("pageshow");
});
```

I have changed the `live` into `on` and the event will fire for sure.

Comment: I changed it to on and it changed the screen but I still don't see the alert message.

Comment: @SheryasD did you uncomment the libraries? I found you have commented the jQuery, jQuery Mobile etc libraries in your header.

Comment: I am loading this page into the DOM using the loadPage and changePage method from another page. So I do not need any info other than the <div data-role="page" id="home"> to load the page correctly, and the page is loading correctly. If you are thinking that the jquery js might not be loaded into the DOM, I have verified that it has. Since, I can do other jquery and jquery mobile related stuff on the page.

Comment: if the files are loaded using Ajax (datz how jQuery Mobile does it) then you should have imported the js file in the previous page itself which loads this page. Else it won't work. Or you gotta refresh the current page once its loaded manually.